# Different behaviour between dialogbox and createdialog is not understood

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, widget

I am creating a dialog in a DLL and while DialogBox creates it - but seems hard to be stopped programmatically, CreateDialog only shows the borders (and title) of the dialog and "does not respond" after creating

I am adding some functionality to an existing program - not under my control. Control of this added functionality - for some external device - requires the user to do some settings particular to settings for this device, not covered by controls in the main program. For this I add a DLL with a small dialog, one with three control elements. The dialog is started with the DialogBox function in a separate thread and funtions well, apart from termination: the use of the main program may want to switch from one device to another without having to explicity quit the dialog by touching some button or control on the dialog.
Therefore I figured it would be better to use CreateDialog since that gives a handle.
However, when doing that - of course adding ShowWindow (handle, WS_SHOW) to make the dialog visible, only the raw widget appears, no controles visible and suffering from "does not respond"

```
`   //  DialogBox (hInstance,`
`    widgetHandle = CreateDialog (hInstance,`
`                        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, ialog1Proc);`
`    err     = GetLastError ();`
`    fprintf (stderr, "Last Error = %d\n", err);`
`       if (err == 0) {`
`          ShowWindow (widgetHandle, SW_SHOW);`
`          while (running)`
`             Sleep (100);`
`       }`
```

Since - when using CreateBox, the contours of the widget - and the title of the dialog - are visible, I assume that the resource is seen correctly,
but it is as such unusable.
Therefore two questions
a. Is my assumption that CreateBox can be used in a thread in a DLL wrong
b. I'm perfectly willing to use DialogBox here, but then I need some advice on how to terminate the dialog (box) programmatically, i.e. from elsewhere in the DLL.
Any help would be appreciated here

Comment: `while (running) Sleep (100);` - with this code (no windows message processing) of course `CreateDialog` will be not work

Comment: The window message processing is in the "dialog1Proc" procedure -not listed here since it is - in case of using CreateDialog not called. CreateDialog is not blocking, so it returns after creating the widget, while DialogBox is blocking. The separate thread is kept alive by letting it run idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DialogBox` creates its own message loop and does not return until the dialog is closed. It is essentially `CreateDialog` + a message loop.

`CreateDialog` returns after creating the window and it expects you to process messages for it.

```
HWND hDlg = CreateDialog(...);
ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_SHOW);
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
  if (!IsWindow(hDlg)) break;
  if (IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg)) continue;
  TranslateMessage(&msg); 
  DispatchMessage(&msg);  
}
```

If your only requirement is to be able to close the dialog from a different thread you can pull it off with `DialogBox` as well:

```
HWND g_hDlg = 0; // Assumes you only have one dialog instance open at the time

.. MyDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT Msg, ..)
{
  switch(Msg)
  {
  case WM_INITDIALOG:
    g_hDlg = hDlg;
    return TRUE;
  case WM_DESTROY:
    g_hDlg = 0;
    break;
  case WM_CLOSE:
    EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
    break;
  }
  return FALSE;
}

EXTERN_C void WINAPI CloseDialog()
{
  if (g_hDlg) SendMessage(g_hDlg, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the CreateDialog function has as one of its parameters the handler for the dialog messages. As such that is not different from creating a dialog with DialogBox. The point is that - in this particular context - there is no error on returning from the createDialog function, only the widget of the dialog - without the controls - is showing and the dialogproc, passed as parameter, is not called once. The context is a thread within a DLL

Comment: Does not matter if it is in a .DLL, you have to pump messages! DS_NOFAILCREATE controls if it should fail if it can't create the children.

Comment: No, you need to pump messages. A window does not work if you don't pump messages.

Comment: Great it works!! Thanx, I did not realize that you need to pump. !!

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks a lot, being a simple linux programmer windows is a completely different world to me. Again Thanks

Comment: A HWND is tied to the thread that created it and if that thread does not pump, the window will not paint correctly when Windows sends `WM_PAINT` etc. and it will not be able to handle user input.